# creating a loss system for voice data in Linux

Tags: networking, network-programming, voice, ns2

how do I create a system that takes in voice data(rtp) and then creates loss in this data(like delay or packet drop/loss)? The output of the system(data) should be readable which made me think i might not be able to use ns-2.Also, ns-2 does not support VBR(needed for voice). I might be wrong in this aspect though. How can I achieve this loss condition in linux environment? please give suggestions.

Comment: also, I forgot to mention that there are commands to do this but i want to do it through a program.

Answer (score 0):

[NIST Net](http://snad.ncsl.nist.gov/nistnet/) looks as if it will do what you want.

Comment: u mean ns2? in that case, can you explain how i might be able to receive the data(that i sent)after allowing it to pass through nodes and errors?